# Implement WCF sync and asyn

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, blocking

I work on WCF.
It should have sync and async implementation The main constraint is **non-blocking** async version
I have implemented this part of the interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(FaultException))]
int Method1(string userName, string companyName);
```

now I should implement the async part of the interface:

//Is it correct interface

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(FaultException))]
Task<int> Method1Async(string userName, string companyName);
//int Method1Async(string userName, string companyName);
```

Is it correct and good for performance to do the following:

```
Task<int> myTask = new Task<string>(() => Method1(userName,companyName));
myTask.Start();
int res = await myTask;
return myTask;//return res;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not good performance at all. Your client side code does not need to know if the server side is sync or async.

Instead just leave your code as `Method1` and on the client code just have the client code generate both synchronous and asynchronous functions.

Via `SvcUtil.exe`

```
svcutil.exe /async /lang:csharp http://YourWcfUrlHere.com
```

Via GUI:
[image]

This will create `int Method1(string userName, string companyName);` and `Task<int> Method1Async(string userName, string companyName);` client side even though only `int Method1(string userName, string companyName);` exists server side.

Comment: -1 If you have control of both sides of the equation, you should you a concrete dll for you interface. In that case you want to include Task based method.

Comment: You may have a different opinion about creating a concrete dll, however does that warrant my answer being considered "not useful"?

Comment: @Aron I edited the question, you should be able to change your votes

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of implementing your `Task` based return.

```
//Not as good, uses more marshaling than really needed.
Task<int> Method1Async(string userName, string companyName)
{
    return Task.Run(() => Method1(username, companyName));
}
```

OR

```
Task<int> Method1Async(string userName, string companyName)
{
    return Task.Result(Method1(username, companyName));
}
```

Notice I haven't used the word `async` once.

Comment: It doesn`t compile Error 1 Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'int' rather than 'Task<int>'

Comment: Note the LACK of the async keyword in the method sig!